# Share ExternalProject between multiple projects in CMake

Tags: makefile, build, cmake, googletest, external-project

I would like to share an ExternalProject between different CMake projects. Imagine a structure like the following:

```
prj1
|- CMakeLists.txt
|- ...
prj2
|- CMakeLists.txt
|- ...
lib
|- ext
 |- gtest
  |- CMakeLists.txt
   |- googletest
    |_ actual_google_test_files
```

What I'm trying to obtain is telling `CMakeLists.txt` to use the gtest in `lib/ext/gtest` with ExternalProject, without re-building gtest everytime in place for each project.

Ideally, gtest gets built once in its folder and projects just use it. I tried using ExternalProject like explained here (http://kaizou.org/2014/11/gtest-cmake/) and including `lib/ext/gtest/CMakeLists.txt` in the projects, but gtest gets re-compiled for every user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr: You should try to integrate google_test as "subproject" not as prebuilt and use a "meta" CMakeLists.txt...

Please read https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/

CMakeLists.txt.in:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.2)
project(googletest-download NONE)
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(googletest
GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
GIT_TAG master
SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src"
BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build"
CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
BUILD_COMMAND ""
INSTALL_COMMAND ""
TEST_COMMAND ""
)
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download" )
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build .
WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download" )

# Prevent GoogleTest from overriding our compiler/linker options
# when building with Visual Studio
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

# Add googletest directly to our build. This adds
# the following targets: gtest, gtest_main, gmock
# and gmock_main
add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src"
             "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build")


add_subdirectory(prj1)
add_subdirectory(prj2)
```

Comment: But won't this compile gtest separately for each single project that uses it?

Comment: Actually you have a choice to do, 1) create a meta cmake so you only have have a "meta-project" thus everything is share between prj1 and prj2, 2) build gtest, [optional install it], use find_package()/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to find it. 3) integrate gtest in each prj if they are independents projects you could have different version/flags/etc of gtest btw...

note: some lib don't have install rule or nor export target to reuse build dir
e.g. abseil-cpp
note2: if you use a CI (travis, appveyor, gitlab) and prj are in separate repo, you'll need gtest for each one...

Comment: also you should be able to use `CC="ccache gcc" CXX="ccache g++" cmake ...` /!\ not tested yet